# Is it possible to DRM EPub files without using any 3rd party software / services?

Tags: adobe, epub, drm

I am looking for a way to add DRM protection to EPub files without buying Adobe software for $6500 or using any 3rd party service. We would like to set up our own DRM server.

Scenario: I upload a hello world EPub file, and the system adds DRM to it. Is it possible?

I hear many times that this is impossible, but could someone clarify why? How exactly does Adobe DRM work and why could not I build my own DRM server?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not building a DRM server. You can do that. The problem is that no standard ereader software or hardware will be able to handle your flavor of DRM and hence users will not be able to read your books. So you will end up having to provide a complete end-to-end environment of both DRM server AND ereader software. If you are in a position to insist that users install your ereader software this may be an option.

Comment: Thanks, could you please provide a link that explains exactly how adobe's DRM server works? Let's say I copy ADEPT EBook to a reader (kindle etc) and attempt to open it. What happens next? Thanks

Comment: @TeflonMac I have building an epub (ebook) reader app. I want the epub download through my app to be used only within my app not else. So can I implement the DRM easily in my app?